# search xml where node name exists sql

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I want to search xml node names not the values. for example

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE Batches( 
   BatchID int,
   RawXml xml
```

and xml column data

```
<CasinoDisbursementReportXmlFile>
   <CasinoDisbursementReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>C234-864</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
          <OrganizationNumber>0002141</OrganizationNumber>
       </ReportHeader>
  </CasinoDisbursementReport>
   <CasinoDisbursementReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>C234-865</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
          <OrganizationNumber>0002141</OrganizationNumber>
       </ReportHeader>
  </CasinoDisbursementReport>
   <CasinoDisbursementReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>C234-866</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
          <OrganizationNumber>0002141</OrganizationNumber>
       </ReportHeader>
  </CasinoDisbursementReport>
   <CasinoDisbursementReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>C234-867</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
          <OrganizationNumber>0002141</OrganizationNumber>
       </ReportHeader>
  </CasinoDisbursementReport>
```

and I want to get only records where OrganizationNumber node exists in the xml column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for something along the lines of this.

```
select Int, Rawxml from Batches 
where CAST(Rawxml AS VARCHAR(MAX)) like '%OrganizationNumber%';
```

edit: I corrected for datatype XML

Comment: exactly I am trying for that but I got bello error  Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of like function.

Comment: I didn't realize it was an XML type. Just add a cast

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select
    report.x.value('OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier[1]', 'varchar(max)') as OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier
from [Batches] b
cross apply b.RawXml.nodes('/CasinoDisbursementReportXmlFile/CasinoDisbursementReport/ReportHeader') report(x)
where report.x.exist('OrganizationNumber') = 1
```

I tested the following script (below) which works fine in SQL Server 2012.

Note that I have removed one of the `OrganizationNumber` elements in the test data below. Note also that you were missing the closing tag `</CasinoDisbursementReportXmlFile>`, I have also added this to the test data below.

```
CREATE TABLE Batches( 
   BatchID int,
   RawXml xml )


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Batches]
           ([BatchID]
           ,[RawXml])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,'<CasinoDisbursementReportXmlFile>
   <CasinoDisbursementReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>C234-864</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
       </ReportHeader>
  </CasinoDisbursementReport>
   <CasinoDisbursementReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>C234-865</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
          <OrganizationNumber>0002141</OrganizationNumber>
       </ReportHeader>
  </CasinoDisbursementReport>
   <CasinoDisbursementReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>C234-866</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
          <OrganizationNumber>0002141</OrganizationNumber>
       </ReportHeader>
  </CasinoDisbursementReport>
   <CasinoDisbursementReport>
       <ReportHeader>
          <OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>C234-867</OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier>
          <OrganizationNumber>0002141</OrganizationNumber>
       </ReportHeader>
  </CasinoDisbursementReport></CasinoDisbursementReportXmlFile>')


select
    report.x.value('OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier[1]', 'varchar(max)') as OrganizationReportReferenceIdentifier
from [Batches] b
cross apply b.RawXml.nodes('/CasinoDisbursementReportXmlFile/CasinoDisbursementReport/ReportHeader') report(x)
where report.x.exist('OrganizationNumber') = 1
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. it is working but I want to select RawXml  when 'OrganizationNumber' exists.